# POwershell not reading MM/DD/YYYY date column from excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

Powershell is reading excel file. the date column in the source excel file is not being read and is returning error. The excel file is generated by dot net program and date column is of the type MM/DD/YYYY.
The code is as below :

```
 foreach($row in $SheetData) {
        if ($row.'HistoricalQuotes Date'.GetType().Name -eq 'Double') { 
            $readingDate = [DateTime]::FromOADate($row.'HistoricalQuotes Date')
        } elseif ($row.'HistoricalQuotes Date'.GetType().Name -eq 'DateTime') {
            $readingDate = $row.'HistoricalQuotes Date'
        } else {
            $readingDate = $null
        }
```

the error returned is :
PS .ps1
Cannot convert argument "d", with value: "10/21/2021", for "FromOADate" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert value "10/21/2021" to type "System.Double". Error:
"Input string was not in a correct format.""

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: The format is either `MM/dd/yyyy` or it's an `OADate`. It can't be both. Which is it?

Comment: Have you considered that "10/21/2021" might just be a string?  Try `[datetime]$row.'HistoricalQuotes Date'`

Comment: Is it a real Excel file (zipped XML or binary) or a CSV that's only renamed as `xsl(x)`?

Comment: Thanks all and @Daniel your solution worked.